# 403 Forbidden Error on domain after tinkering with Apache, SHELL, Certbot

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, apache2

I was trying to figure out how to install SSL on my site using let's encrypt with Certbot. My host is BlueHost, which is unsupported. In the process of installing certbot, tinkering with Apache files (to enable/setup virtual hosts), connecting through SHELL (had some authentication issues), my domain is now 403 Forbidden from all browsers on my laptop (MacOS/terminal) (but not from any other computers/devices on my network). I can still ping my domain successfully from terminal. I re-disabled the virtual hosts, deleted my virtual host information, and contacted BlueHost to see if my IP had been blacklisted due to failed authentication to no avail. I really have no idea where to begin troubleshooting now.

Edit: 
Contents of httpd-vhosts.conf

```
 # Virtual Hosts
 #
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
 # machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" 
common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: post your virtual host file

Comment: I posted my virtual host file. I have also stopped apache service, which has led to the Forbidden 403 message to change to "It Works!" (which is the same message I was getting when I switched Apache from local host 8888 to 80 earlier... no idea iff/how that's related, but it definitely seems to be an Apache issue).

Comment: Try this configuration https://pastebin.com/zq2v38xY

Comment: I changed to the configuration you pasted. I'm still receiving the "It works!" page. When I stop apache, I get "page not found." I feel like I may have somehow set up an alias that redirects from my domain to the local apache file.

Comment: The "it works" is the default you get without v-hosts enabled. Try enabling virtualhosts again

Comment: I have enabled virtual hosts in the httpd configuration file. I'm still getting "It Works"

Comment: did you change the server name in the v-host file to the correct url?. Also make sure the file path is correct. v-host uses the server name to send you to site you configured, not the IP. That's what allows multiple sites on the same IP. Connecting by IP address normally lands you at the "it works" default page. Another trick is to disable the default page by running the command `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This is frustrating me quite a bit. I don't want any virtual hosts running. I just want my domain "dan-teacher.com" to show me the internet version of "dan-teacher.com" rather than redirecting to something local. I don't know what I did to cause this, but I just want to undo it. Even if I get rid of the default page, it won't help.

Comment: "redirecting to something local"? impossible and your page is working, I just visited it.

Comment: When I type "dan-teacher.com" into my browser on my laptop, I get the "it works" mesage. On every other device, it works fine. I have no idea why, but it seems to be something local because when I stop the apache service, it changes to "not found" rather than "it works."

Comment: Run `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and look for an entry showing dan-teacher.com, I suggest renaming it to something like dan-teacher.local and use that url for your local development. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Dave. I figured it at the same time as you answered! I didn't remember tinkering with hosts, but that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had tinkered with /etc/hosts (I'm not sure which guide told me to do that). Anyway, once I fixed that, everything was solved. Thanks to Dave Carruthers for his help.